# Changing a Logo: What is the Name of this Little Image File?

Tags: kylin

I have this desktop in Ubuntu Kylin 14.04

[image]

but in the top right hand corner I have the apple logo due to use of the MBuntu-XL theme.

The file is located somewhere within /usr/local/icons/MBuntu-XL/....

but there are thousands of icons and I can't find it.

Does anyone know its name (or part of its name) so I can replace it?

Comment: why the downvote? How else am I meant to answer this question?

Comment: 1) I use Ubuntu Kylin. 2) Why offer a tag "kylin" when its all off topic??

Comment: **My apologies!  You're right and I was wrong!  Ubuntu Kylin is an official release!**  It's just not on the official release yet.  I'll try to get that updates shortly.  (Please delete your first comment so that mine will move more to the top so that the next reviewer can see my bold comment!)
P.S. And that's Why I always leave a comment *before* downvoting and await a response!  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called `launcher_bfb.png`.

It is actually located in `/usr/share/unity/icons/`.

Comment: What you pointed out is for "launcher" icon not for "System settings" icon!!

Comment: so where's the system setting icon?

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you were trying to do and had run in to the same problem myself with the launcher icon. This time look in usr/share/icons for the theme you're currently using and then looks for system-devices-panel.svg (I found mine under /status/22)